# How do I used values declared in XML on my custom layout?

Tags: android

Im creating a custom layout and I want to use the text declared in the `layout.xml` file in my layout.

Like when I create a `TextView` in XML and set `android:text=@string/text1` when I run the app text view automatically loads the text from android:text. So how can I access attributes declared in the layout XML file in my custom component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have learn how to do it from this:

[WebImageView: Buy one, get two!](http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/11/23/droid-fu-part-2-webimageview-and-webgalleryadapter/)

In simple steps:

- [Define the string of your XMLS](http://github.com/kaeppler/droid-fu/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/droidfu/DroidFu.java).
- [Get the attributes in the code](http://github.com/kaeppler/droid-fu/blob/770f2e45f13d82a154364188362fa8331395b143/src/main/java/com/github/droidfu/widgets/WebImageView.java).

Answer (score 0):

Did you complete the Android Developer [Tutorials](http://developer.android.com/resources/index.html)? The [Hello, Views | Relative Layout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html) tutorial will walk you through how to do this.

Comment: Never seen the answer to his question there. I would like if you could give the exact link if it exists.

Comment: You are correct, it is in the Notepad Tutorial (http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad), not the Hello, Views | Relative Layout tutorial, and the project exercises archive (.zip) containing the source is needed. An example of this question is covered in Notepadv2Solution, for example: mBodyText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.body);

Comment: Sorry, but I think you misunderstood his question.